# Foursquare returns "Invalid mention" when adding a check-in

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to add a check-in with a mention, but it fails returning:

```
'meta' =>
  array (
    'code' => 400,
    'errorType' => 'param_error',
    'errorDetail' => 'Invalid mention: (10,27,2147775)',
  )
```

These are the parameters I used:

```
array (
  'venueId' => '4d9c6d228efaa14376464cb7',
  'shout' => ' — with Rihards Ščeredins',
  'll' => '56.9262,24.02096',
  'mentions' => '10,27,2147775',
)
```

I used the same syntax in the shout message as Foursquare does " — with " followed by the mentioned user names.

Why it fails to add the check-in? Does the mentioned friends name in shout has to match the user's Foursquare name? Cause currently it does not..

**Update:**
I thought it could be related to multi-byte character length but after playing around these both fail with the same error.

Using mb_strlen and mb_strpos:
`'shout' => ' — with Rihards Ščeredins'` with indices `'8,25,2147775'`

Using strlen and strpos:
`'shout' => ' — with Rihards Ščeredins'` with indices `'10,29,2147775'`

Any idea what else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

The first two numbers of the comma-delimited string are the indices in the string where the mention goes. Your string has 25 characters, yet you index all the way out to 27. Your mentions param should probably be something like `"8,25,2147775"`

Comment: Damn does multi byte characters. `strlen(" — with ")` returns 10 however `mb_strlen(" — with ")` returns 8.

Comment: Updated my question. Still getting no luck.